# Change and display element from an array

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

I have this awstat file of lists the country code and how many visits and hits:

```
# Domain - Pages - Hits - Bandwidth
BEGIN_DOMAIN 1
ua 245 245 970690 
us 90 647 10311747 
cn 27 27 106974 
ru 25 26 99953 
gb 12 82 1155179 
fr 7 7 41230 
kr 4 4 15848 
de 4 15 211641 
in 3 15 234340 
ph 2 2 7924 
lv 2 2 0 
ro 2 2 13856 
il 1 1 3962 
dk 1 1 3962 
vn 1 1 3962 
nl 1 1 3962 
lt 1 1 3962 
ca 0 1 20264 
END_DOMAIN
```

I'm trying to extract it and displays it by countries with nombre of pages per country, so I tried this:

```
preg_match("/BEGIN_DOMAIN(.*)END_DOMAIN/is", $awstats, $matches);
$country = $matches[0] ; 
awstats_extract_country($country) ;
```

which calls the function `awstats_extract_country($country)` :

```
function awstats_extract_country($country)
{   
    $country = explode("\n", $country) ; 
    unset($country[(count($country)-1)]) ; 
    unset($country[0]) ; 
    foreach ($country as $key => $value)
    $country[$key] = explode(" ", $value) ; 

    //print_array($sider);
    $fields = array(

        0 => "Country" ,
        1 => "Pages" ,
        2 => "Hits" ,
        3 => "Bandwidth" ,
    ) ; 
    echo '<div id="collapse_awstats_extract_sider" class="accordion-body collapse in">';
        echo '<div class="accordion-inner">';
            print_table($country, $fields); 
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

But it displays me countries abbreviated just like in the file is there a way i can show them in names of countries, I mean for `ua` ==> `UKRAINE`and so on just like here http://www.iso.org/iso/fr/french_country_names_and_code_elements.htm

Much appreciated

Comment: I think, this could be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143252/convert-country-name-to-country-code-abbreviations-php or http://snipplr.com/view/36868/

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there's no built-in function which converts 2 letter country code to country name, so you have to make a look-up table (using array or database), like [this question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143252)