# getting dropdown text from database value as selected default

Tags: php, dropdown

```
<span class="userlabel">Country: </span><br> <select id="billingCountry" name="billingCountry">
    <option value="<?php echo $eachData['billingCountry']; ?>"><?php echo $eachData['billingCountry']; ?></option>
    <option value="AA">Country A</option>
    <option value="BB">Country B</option>
    <option value="CC">Country C</option>
    <option value="DD">Country D</option>
    <option value="EE">Country E</option>
 </select>
```

Say I have a database that only stores the country value (country codes i.e SG, MY, IR, IS) and would like to show the text of the country based on the value from my database as my default dropdown option. Is there an efficient way of doing this since the list of countries is overwhelming?

So let's say the database stored "SG", I would like "Singapore" to be shown instead of "SG" as the default value.

For my actual dropdown list I'm using these values from http://www.textfixer.com/resources/dropdowns/country-dropdown-iso-html.txt

edit: thank you for all the different variations!

Comment: You could use this [Array](https://gist.github.com/vxnick/380904) so you can match the code with the right value.

Comment: @Naruto Thank you! Just what I needed. p.s A+ for naruto name

Comment: You are welcome, and thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
<?php
function getCountry($code) {
    $countries = Array(
                    "NL" => "Netherlands",
                    "SG" => "Singapore",
                    "UK" => "United Kingdom"
                );

    return $countries[$code];
}

echo getCountry("SG");
?>
```

**Edit: Misunderstood your question, updated code**

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.
The first is to run the c ode through this function with the `-` (minus) symbol before it.

```
$name = Locale::getDisplayRegion("-{$code}");
```

I have not thoroughly tested this for all of your country codes.
The second, would be to create a large associative array where the key is the country code and the value is the name.

You could then pull the name out like so:

```
$name = $assocArray[$code];
```

Answer (score 1):

Preference method : First of all, you have to map your database with the correct pair of countries.

So, you can use another column to be your value.

Optional method : You can pairing within the code by using array like :

```
$country = array
(
'AF' => 'Afghanistan',
'AX' => 'Aland Islands',
'AL' => 'Albania',
'DZ' => 'Algeria',
'AS' => 'American Samoa',
'AD' => 'Andorra',
'AO' => 'Angola',
'AI' => 'Anguilla',
'AQ' => 'Antarctica',
'AG' => 'Antigua And Barbuda',
'AR' => 'Argentina',
'AM' => 'Armenia',
'AW' => 'Aruba',
'AU' => 'Australia',
'AT' => 'Austria',
'AZ' => 'Azerbaijan',
'BS' => 'Bahamas',
'BH' => 'Bahrain',
'BD' => 'Bangladesh',
'BB' => 'Barbados',
'BY' => 'Belarus',
'BE' => 'Belgium',
'BZ' => 'Belize',
'BJ' => 'Benin',
'BM' => 'Bermuda',
'BT' => 'Bhutan',
'BO' => 'Bolivia',
'BA' => 'Bosnia And Herzegovina',
'BW' => 'Botswana',
'BV' => 'Bouvet Island',
'BR' => 'Brazil',
'IO' => 'British Indian Ocean Territory',
'BN' => 'Brunei Darussalam',
'BG' => 'Bulgaria',
'BF' => 'Burkina Faso',
'BI' => 'Burundi',
'KH' => 'Cambodia',
'CM' => 'Cameroon',
'CA' => 'Canada',
'CV' => 'Cape Verde',
'KY' => 'Cayman Islands',
'CF' => 'Central African Republic',
'TD' => 'Chad',
'CL' => 'Chile',
'CN' => 'China',
'CX' => 'Christmas Island',
'CC' => 'Cocos (Keeling) Islands',
'CO' => 'Colombia',
'KM' => 'Comoros',
'CG' => 'Congo',
'CD' => 'Congo, Democratic Republic',
'CK' => 'Cook Islands',
'CR' => 'Costa Rica',
'CI' => 'Cote D\'Ivoire',
'HR' => 'Croatia',
'CU' => 'Cuba',
'CY' => 'Cyprus',
'CZ' => 'Czech Republic',
'DK' => 'Denmark',
'DJ' => 'Djibouti',
'DM' => 'Dominica',
'DO' => 'Dominican Republic',
'EC' => 'Ecuador',
'EG' => 'Egypt',
'SV' => 'El Salvador',
'GQ' => 'Equatorial Guinea',
'ER' => 'Eritrea',
'EE' => 'Estonia',
'ET' => 'Ethiopia',
'FK' => 'Falkland Islands (Malvinas)',
'FO' => 'Faroe Islands',
'FJ' => 'Fiji',
'FI' => 'Finland',
'FR' => 'France',
'GF' => 'French Guiana',
'PF' => 'French Polynesia',
'TF' => 'French Southern Territories',
'GA' => 'Gabon',
'GM' => 'Gambia',
'GE' => 'Georgia',
'DE' => 'Germany',
'GH' => 'Ghana',
'GI' => 'Gibraltar',
'GR' => 'Greece',
'GL' => 'Greenland',
'GD' => 'Grenada',
'GP' => 'Guadeloupe',
'GU' => 'Guam',
'GT' => 'Guatemala',
'GG' => 'Guernsey',
'GN' => 'Guinea',
'GW' => 'Guinea-Bissau',
'GY' => 'Guyana',
'HT' => 'Haiti',
'HM' => 'Heard Island & Mcdonald Islands',
'VA' => 'Holy See (Vatican City State)',
'HN' => 'Honduras',
'HK' => 'Hong Kong',
'HU' => 'Hungary',
'IS' => 'Iceland',
'IN' => 'India',
'ID' => 'Indonesia',
'IR' => 'Iran, Islamic Republic Of',
'IQ' => 'Iraq',
'IE' => 'Ireland',
'IM' => 'Isle Of Man',
'IL' => 'Israel',
'IT' => 'Italy',
'JM' => 'Jamaica',
'JP' => 'Japan',
'JE' => 'Jersey',
'JO' => 'Jordan',
'KZ' => 'Kazakhstan',
'KE' => 'Kenya',
'KI' => 'Kiribati',
'KR' => 'Korea',
'KW' => 'Kuwait',
'KG' => 'Kyrgyzstan',
'LA' => 'Lao People\'s Democratic Republic',
'LV' => 'Latvia',
'LB' => 'Lebanon',
'LS' => 'Lesotho',
'LR' => 'Liberia',
'LY' => 'Libyan Arab Jamahiriya',
'LI' => 'Liechtenstein',
'LT' => 'Lithuania',
'LU' => 'Luxembourg',
'MO' => 'Macao',
'MK' => 'Macedonia',
'MG' => 'Madagascar',
'MW' => 'Malawi',
'MY' => 'Malaysia',
'MV' => 'Maldives',
'ML' => 'Mali',
'MT' => 'Malta',
'MH' => 'Marshall Islands',
'MQ' => 'Martinique',
'MR' => 'Mauritania',
'MU' => 'Mauritius',
'YT' => 'Mayotte',
'MX' => 'Mexico',
'FM' => 'Micronesia, Federated States Of',
'MD' => 'Moldova',
'MC' => 'Monaco',
'MN' => 'Mongolia',
'ME' => 'Montenegro',
'MS' => 'Montserrat',
'MA' => 'Morocco',
'MZ' => 'Mozambique',
'MM' => 'Myanmar',
'NA' => 'Namibia',
'NR' => 'Nauru',
'NP' => 'Nepal',
'NL' => 'Netherlands',
'AN' => 'Netherlands Antilles',
'NC' => 'New Caledonia',
'NZ' => 'New Zealand',
'NI' => 'Nicaragua',
'NE' => 'Niger',
'NG' => 'Nigeria',
'NU' => 'Niue',
'NF' => 'Norfolk Island',
'MP' => 'Northern Mariana Islands',
'NO' => 'Norway',
'OM' => 'Oman',
'PK' => 'Pakistan',
'PW' => 'Palau',
'PS' => 'Palestinian Territory, Occupied',
'PA' => 'Panama',
'PG' => 'Papua New Guinea',
'PY' => 'Paraguay',
'PE' => 'Peru',
'PH' => 'Philippines',
'PN' => 'Pitcairn',
'PL' => 'Poland',
'PT' => 'Portugal',
'PR' => 'Puerto Rico',
'QA' => 'Qatar',
'RE' => 'Reunion',
'RO' => 'Romania',
'RU' => 'Russian Federation',
'RW' => 'Rwanda',
'BL' => 'Saint Barthelemy',
'SH' => 'Saint Helena',
'KN' => 'Saint Kitts And Nevis',
'LC' => 'Saint Lucia',
'MF' => 'Saint Martin',
'PM' => 'Saint Pierre And Miquelon',
'VC' => 'Saint Vincent And Grenadines',
'WS' => 'Samoa',
'SM' => 'San Marino',
'ST' => 'Sao Tome And Principe',
'SA' => 'Saudi Arabia',
'SN' => 'Senegal',
'RS' => 'Serbia',
'SC' => 'Seychelles',
'SL' => 'Sierra Leone',
'SG' => 'Singapore',
'SK' => 'Slovakia',
'SI' => 'Slovenia',
'SB' => 'Solomon Islands',
'SO' => 'Somalia',
'ZA' => 'South Africa',
'GS' => 'South Georgia And Sandwich Isl.',
'ES' => 'Spain',
'LK' => 'Sri Lanka',
'SD' => 'Sudan',
'SR' => 'Suriname',
'SJ' => 'Svalbard And Jan Mayen',
'SZ' => 'Swaziland',
'SE' => 'Sweden',
'CH' => 'Switzerland',
'SY' => 'Syrian Arab Republic',
'TW' => 'Taiwan',
'TJ' => 'Tajikistan',
'TZ' => 'Tanzania',
'TH' => 'Thailand',
'TL' => 'Timor-Leste',
'TG' => 'Togo',
'TK' => 'Tokelau',
'TO' => 'Tonga',
'TT' => 'Trinidad And Tobago',
'TN' => 'Tunisia',
'TR' => 'Turkey',
'TM' => 'Turkmenistan',
'TC' => 'Turks And Caicos Islands',
'TV' => 'Tuvalu',
'UG' => 'Uganda',
'UA' => 'Ukraine',
'AE' => 'United Arab Emirates',
'GB' => 'United Kingdom',
'US' => 'United States',
'UM' => 'United States Outlying Islands',
'UY' => 'Uruguay',
'UZ' => 'Uzbekistan',
'VU' => 'Vanuatu',
'VE' => 'Venezuela',
'VN' => 'Viet Nam',
'VG' => 'Virgin Islands, British',
'VI' => 'Virgin Islands, U.S.',
'WF' => 'Wallis And Futuna',
'EH' => 'Western Sahara',
'YE' => 'Yemen',
'ZM' => 'Zambia',
'ZW' => 'Zimbabwe',
);
```

and you using

```
$country[$eachData['billingCountry']]
```

instead of your $eachData['billingCountry'].
This method please make sure that you can map the selected country back into the same data when you sending to check within the database.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143252/convert-country-name-to-country-code-abbreviations-php

Comment: Best way is using database, @NanaPartykar have referenced insertion statement for you.